# How can I ignore certain values when comparing dictionaries in unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to assert that two dictionaries are equal, using Python's [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), but ignoring the values of certain keys in the dictionary, in a convenient syntax, like this:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

class Example(TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        result = foobar()
        self.assertEqual(
            result,
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "year_of_birth": 1980,
                "image_url": ignore(), # how to do this?
                "unique_id": ignore(), #
            },
        )
```

To be clear, I want to check that all four keys exist, and I want to check the values of `"name"` and `"year_of_birth"`, (but not `"image_url"` or `"unique_id`"), and I want to check that no other keys exist.

I know I could modify `result` here to the key-value pairs for `"image_url"` and `"unique_id"`, but I would like something more convenient that doesn't modify the original dictionary.

(This is inspired by [`Test::Deep`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep#ignore) for Perl 5.)

Comment: So you want to assert that `result['name'] == 'John Smith'` and `result['year_of_birth'] == 1980`?

Comment: Probably you also want to assert that the keys `'image_url'` and `'unique_id'` do exist in `result`?

Comment: Yes, I want to check the values of `name`, and `year_of_birth`, I want to check that `image_url` and `unique_id` exist (but I do not care what the value is set to), and I want to check that there are no other keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [`unittest.mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) which compares equal to everything.

```
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest.mock as mock

class Example(TestCase):
    def test_happy_path(self):
        result = {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "year_of_birth": 1980,
            "image_url": 42,
            "unique_id": 'foo'
        }
        self.assertEqual(
            result,
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "year_of_birth": 1980,
                "image_url": mock.ANY,
                "unique_id": mock.ANY
            }
        )

    def test_missing_key(self):
        result = {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "year_of_birth": 1980,
            "unique_id": 'foo'
        }
        self.assertNotEqual(
            result,
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "year_of_birth": 1980,
                "image_url": mock.ANY,
                "unique_id": mock.ANY
            }
        )

    def test_extra_key(self):
        result = {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "year_of_birth": 1980,
            "image_url": 42,
            "unique_id": 'foo',
            "maiden_name": 'Doe'
        }
        self.assertNotEqual(
            result,
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "year_of_birth": 1980,
                "image_url": mock.ANY,
                "unique_id": mock.ANY
            }
        )

    def test_wrong_value(self):
        result = {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "year_of_birth": 1918,
            "image_url": 42,
            "unique_id": 'foo'
        }
        self.assertNotEqual(
            result,
            {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "year_of_birth": 1980,
                "image_url": mock.ANY,
                "unique_id": mock.ANY
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a follow up question if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627499/why-doesnt-unittest-mock-any-work-correctly-with-django-objects . No worries if not, I'll be looking into it myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply ignore the selected keys in the `result` dictionary.

```
self.assertEqual({k: v for k, v in result.items()
                  if k not in ('image_url', 'unique_id')},
                 {"name": "John Smith",
                  "year_of_birth": 1980})
```

Comment: This doesn't check that the keys `"image_url"` and `"unique_id"` exist. I only want to ignore their values. Also, I'm really hoping for something as elegant as `ignore()` in the imaginary code in the question.

Comment: Oh I see. It wasn't clear to me from the question.  In this case mock.ANY is a better solution.