# Why doesn't unittest.mock.ANY work correctly with Django objects?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing

I have written a test in Django, and I'm [using `unittest.mock.ANY` to ignore certain values in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627010/247696). Here is the test:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import unittest.mock as mock

class Example(TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='example')
        result = {'user': user, 'number': 42}
        self.assertEqual(
            result,
            {'user': mock.ANY, 'number': 42}
        )
```

If I run this test, I expect it to pass. Instead, I get this failure:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_example (example.tests.Example)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example/tests.py", line 18, in test_example
    'number': 42,
AssertionError: {'user': <User: example>, 'number': 42} != {'user': <ANY>, 'number': 42}
- {'number': 42, 'user': <User: example>}
?                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

+ {'number': 42, 'user': <ANY>}
?                         ^^^
```

Why doesn't [`ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) work in this case? It seems to work with strings and numbers.

Comment: What if you compare it the other way: `self.assertEqual({'user': mock.ANY, 'number': 42}, result)`?

Comment: `assertEqual` is attempting to evaluate `user == mock.ANY`, which is implemented as `user.__eq__(mock.ANY)`, not `mock.ANY.__eq__(user)`. `type(user).__eq__` appears to be returning `False` rather than raising `NotImplemented`, which would allow `mock.ANY.__eq__` to be tried.

Comment: Flipping the order, as suggested by Goyo, would allow `mock.ANY.__eq__` to be tried first.

Comment: @chepner Sounds like an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assertEqual`, in the course of comparing its two arguments, evaluates the expression `user == mock.ANY`. In standard fashion, the *left* argument determines which function actually implements `==`. In this case, you have `user.__eq__(mock.ANY)`. It appears that whatever type `user` is, its `__eq__` method simply returns `False` for an unexpected type. If it raised `NotImplemented` instead, the language would fall back on `mock.ANY.__eq__(user)`, which could return `True`.

If you change the call to

```
self.assertEqual(
            {'user': mock.ANY, 'number': 42},
            result,
        )
```

then the resulting comparison `mock.ANY == user` will return `True` as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Python's documentation usually indicates that the expected result is the second argument, and the argument to be tested is the first argument, like this: `self.assertEqual(got, expected)`. But I suppose `assertEqual` works equally as well if the order of these arguments is reversed.